How to get the mixed audio stream of windows 11 or Linux and apply own FIR filter to it?
I am currently trying to create a global equalizer for Windows 11 and therefore need access the mixed audio stream. I would very much appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction regarding how to access and influence global audio in windows 11.
Is there a way to signal to windows that your program is to be recognized as an audio endpoint? For example there is a equalizer application which is recorgnized by my system in the same way that a pair of headphones would be recognized, then the application itself redirects the audio to the actual speakers. Is there a way to access the mixed audio stream using Windows SDK? Do I need to write a new audio driver in order to achieve it? And how come adio signal processing devices into play, which I can find inside the device manager? Is there a way to declare a programm as an APO, but still the question remains how i can get the output samples.
I haven't tried anything concrete yet, because I have no idea where to start and don't want to spend houres reading unrelated information, therefore  I am asking for where to start my research.
If anyone knows how to do this in Linux/Ubuntu I would be happy to switch my focus on Linux machines. My only requirement is that all audio travels through my FIR-Filter.
I need this information in order to write my bachelors thesis for which I have only 9 days left to complete, therefore I would really appreciate any tips or advice on how to implement my FIR-Filter.
Regards, Fritz!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
